# Data processing AWK

Tags: awk

I have created a shell script which filters certain data based on the input file that I write in the console. But now I have approximately like 30 files to be filtered and I was wondering if I could write all these files (PATH) that needed to be filtered in an .txt file and invoke it in the main awk file to filter each one of them without typing one by one in the console.

Regards.

awk -f "filter.awk" data.txt

data.txt should have file names:
prueba1.tr
prueba2.tr
     .
     .
prueba30.tr

The filter in awk should read each one of the files inside data.txt. If there is a match then it proceeds to open the file a process the data inside. At the moment to do this I am just using if(ARGV[1]=="name of the file.tr") {proceed with the filtering process} But I have approximately 30 files and I would like to automatize this a bit.

Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Yes, you can. If that's not the answer you wanted then please edit your question to clarify what it is you are asking, with examples.

Comment: Hello @EdMorton , How could I do this? I have been trying but I always get an empty file.

Comment: As I said, edit your question to clarify what you are asking and provide sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file1
foo
$ cat file2
bar
$ cat data.txt
file1
file2

$ awk 'NR==FNR{ARGV[ARGC]=$0; ARGC++; next} {print FILENAME, $0}' data.txt
file1 foo
file2 bar
```

or if you prefer (a bit more efficient since `NR==FNR` isn't getting tested for every line of every file):

```
$ awk -v list="data.txt" 'BEGIN{ while ( (getline line < list) > 0 ) { ARGV[ARGC]=line; ARGC++ } close(list) } {print FILENAME, $0}'
file1 foo
file2 bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, if `files.txt` has the list of your files, and `yourCommand.sh`is your script that accepts a file as a parameter, you can do

```
cat files.txt | xargs -L 1 yourCommand.sh
```

That will feed in each line of `files.txt` to `yourCommand.sh` one by one.  It doesn't use `awk`, but I think it accomplishes what you wanted.

Note:  I don't care that its a 'useless use of cat'

Answer (score 1):

awk can take multiple input files and does the processing one by one.  If you want to have the output collected in the same file, it's a typical awk use case.

For example, if you ran your script as

```
awk -f script.awk inputfile > outputfile
```

You can extend to multiple files

```
awk -f script.awk inputfile1 inputfile2 ... > outputfile
```

or, if using standard naming

```
awk -f script.awk inputfile{1..30} > outputile
```

or, all your files are in a directory

```
awk -f script.awk inputfiles/* > outputile
```

etc,

If you want one output per input file, you need redirection in the script.  Since we don't know what your script is I'm going to present a simple case.

For example, this will print the headers (first lines) of the input files indexed 1 to 30 to corresponding output files

```
awk 'FNR==1{print > FILENAME".out"}' inputfiles{1..30}
```

Comment: hello @shellter . I was trying to do as you told me but all the information of the other files and even from it self got recorded in the first output file. I don't know if maybe do to a loop this is happening.

Comment: For multiple output files, you have to modify your script and do the redirection there.  As I tried to explain above, this is suitable for single output file only.

Comment: @karakfa: Sorry, I missed that you needed individual output per listed input file. So `awk 'FNR==1{print > FILENAME".out"}' $(cat list.txt)` should work, per karakfa well reasoned answer. This assumes there are no spaces in the filename contained in `list.txt`. Good luck to all!